# Does it make sense for a class Logger to be copyable and movable?

Tags: c++

I'm asking a lot of questions here lately. I'm contemplating about semantics.

Nothing makes copying or moving it difficult, in fact it only has one member function log() and no data members (probably in future). But to me it seems logically incorrect for an object of such type to be copyable and movable.

Comment: If it has no data members, why is it an object to begin with?

Comment: @delnan, it might have in future. To enable other types of logging, not just console output.

Comment: @delnan More importantly: if it has only one function, why is it an object to begin with? It sounds like a function.

Comment: If you don't really know what your object is supposed to do in the future it's kinda hard to figure out if it makes sense to be copyable/movable. As far now without any data members it doesn't really matter...

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to have only one loggin for the whole process then use a static object and no need to copy and delete the objects

If you plan to have a limited number of objects (one per logging level for example) and that these objects are heavy (large buffer, odbc connection) then it is worth having a movable and copyable class.

However, you cannot have a mutex in a copyable class because the mutex are not copyable.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: a logger is kind of like an output stream, so do the same as for streams. Movable but not copyable.

Long answer: this breaks into two decisions, each in two parts:

- Should I make the logger interface that this type satisfies, guarantee copyable and movable?

Future logger types predictably will contain streams or mutexes, which means the interface should not guarantee copyable because those things are not copyable. A `vector` of loggers might make some sense, so it's not completely pointless to make loggers movable provided you don't see a specific reason not to.

- Should I make this class copyable and movable?

It probably doesn't matter, except that you say you're planning to add data members in future. That is to say, you're going to modify this logger class instead of writing new logger classes that satisfy the same basic interface with a different sink for the log messages. *If you're certain that's wise*, then for that reason the same considerations apply to this class as to the interface: don't make it copyable. Movable probably won't do any harm and does some slight good.